# I'm lost at how to configure my code so that , when i click the radio button a certain image appears

Tags: c#

I have to create a small pizza delivery program in C# using Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition :

It has 3 Radio Buttons ( for 3 different pizza's), A Textblock for text ( to show the ingredients), and an image to show the type of pizza.

So I want that when I click on one of those 3 Radio Buttons, a certain text & image appears.

The Radio Buttons and TextBlock is ok, but the image I'm lost at how to properly configure it using the code behind.

Can anyone check the code, and maybe enlighten me?

https://ideone.com/e.js/MjEBnd

```
     private void radiobtnHawai_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string Hawai = "Ananas, Kip, Kaas";
            lbl1.Text = Hawai;

            Image Hawai.jpg = new Image();
            BitmapImage bi3 = new BitmapImage();
            bi3.BeginInit();
            bi3.UriSource = new Uri("smiley_stackpanel.PNG", UriKind.Relative);
            bi3.EndInit();
            Hawai.jpg.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
            Hawai.jpg.Source = bi3;
        }
```

Here is an Extra Image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiHRn.png

Thanks in Advance,

***If more information is needed, please don't hesitate to ask.***

Comment: (I am assuming this is for WinForms, and as it looks like school work, I won't give you the whole answer but point you to where you can find it) There is a [Picture Box control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox?view=netframework-4.8) that is useful for displaying images. The link has an example as well

Comment: Can you please share the xaml if this is wpf?

Comment: It appareantly is too long to paste in here:

Comment: You have to give diff IDs to each and when you click on it, you have to identify the ID and according to it you have to show the image

Comment: Here is the ideone link:https://ideone.com/e.js/GZ6c2Q

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a image control defined like this

```
<Image Name="ImageViewer1" Height="400" Width="400" />
```

On your radio  checked command , you have to assign the source of "ImageViewer1".
For example, in your case it will look like this

```
 private void radiobtnHawai_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string Hawai = "Ananas, Kip, Kaas";
            lbl1.Text = Hawai;


            BitmapImage bi3 = new BitmapImage();
            bi3.BeginInit();
            bi3.UriSource = new Uri("smiley_stackpanel.PNG", UriKind.Relative);
            bi3.EndInit();
            ImageViewer1.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
            ImageViewer1.Source = bi3;
        }
```

Also make sure that, smiley_stackpanel.PNG, exists in your Environment.CurrentDirectory.
By specifying relative path it will look images from the path where your exe resides